# Compile error "Error stray '\240' in program" using DevC++

Tags: c, compiler-errors, dev-c++

My code is the very simple [breadth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) (BFS) algorithm. But the compiler sent me the:

> Error stray '\240'

Why?

[image]

Comment: Not related to the problem, but why do you code C in a .cpp file? .cpp files are for C++. C uses the .c file extension.

Comment: Don't post images of text! Also C and C++ are different languages which happen to share some similar **syntax**. However, as semantics can differ, never compile C code with a C++ compiler and vice versa!

Comment: ok i tried .c file but still not working . thahts not main reason.

Comment: You need to start with a blank file, and type the code by hand. Either that, or write a simple program that reads the file, and replaces the `\240` characters with spaces.

Comment: Paste text in MS word first and while pasting select 'Keep text Only' and then select it from ms word, all the ASCII characters causing errors will be removed and this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have probably copied this from somewhere and there are some non-ASCII characters. Open it with some editor where you can see all characters and you will see some strange signs.

The problem is connected to intentions.

Comment: What do you mean by *"The problem is connected to intentions."*? Can you elaborate?